# Rails 4: Attribute Validation -- specific example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm pretty new to Rails, so I'm having a tough time deciphering what should be a relatively simple problem. I have a model, and I want its `semester` attribute (a string) to either be in the form:

"Fall [4 numbers]" or "Spring [4 numbers]". For instance, "Fall 2013" would be valid, "Spring 2015 would be valid", "Spring 20151" would be invalid, and so forth. What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
validates :semester, format: {with: /\A(Spring|Fall) \d{4}\z/}
```